# $('video').get(0).currentTime not working on iPhone/iPad

Tags: jquery, iphone, mobile, video

im jumping through different chapters of a movie by setting "currentTime" to xxx seconds. 
Therefore i have a screen where you can click on so-called "pads" - one per chapter.

If you click on the pad the pad-screen fades out, the movie fades in and start right where it should (see code below). This is perfectly working on any browser. But its NOT working on mobile devices like iPad/iPod/iPhone. I found out that the problem is this

```
$('video').get(0).currentTime =
```

And here is the code:

```
    $('.chapter_pad a').each( function(index) {
    $(this).click( function() {
        currentVid = index;
        endTime = videos[index]["end"];
        $("#startscreen").fadeOut(0, function() {
            $("#vids").fadeIn(0, function() {
                $('#video').get(0).currentTime = videos[index]["start"];
                $('#video').get(0).play();

            });
        });
    });
});
```

Explanation:
["start"] and ["end"] are elements from an assoziative array that i created before. This assoziative array holds the chapternames, start- and end-times etc.

Any ideas to solve this are appreciated!

Thanks in advance!
Fab

Comment: Do you see an error in your debugger?

Comment: honestly here i just have an iPod - not sure how to debug on that.

Comment: If you go into device settings you can enable the developer bar for Safari

Comment: ok - it shows up the followin error:
Javascript-Error in line 135
http://localhost/~me/app/js/script.js
INVALID_SATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or no longer usable.

Maybe thats cause the browser always open up the native controls when playing a video in browser?

Any hints?

    Ohh - and the line 135 is exactly the one with "$('#video').get(0).currentTime = videos[index]["start"];"

Comment: Looks like someone else had the same problem - I did a google search on your exception and eventually found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252062/playing-html5-video-on-ipad-and-seeking/11252343

Comment: thank you - the problem was that i tried to jump somewhere even the video wasnt there. So i used the css translate(-3000px) to push the video out of the window. I could set the currentTime then ;)
But: The problem is, that the iPad jumps to 6.5999999948 even i set 7.